# SQL Connection Open Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project which, up until today, has been fine.  However now when I run it and it goes through a few different `Stored Procedure` calls it is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` with the message `The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.`

I get that I could put in a check to see if the connection is already open, but this code hasn't changed (it is under `Version Control` and isn't modified) so I'm looking for other potential explanations.

Could there be some lock in SQL which isn't being released?  Is there a process which I should look out for and kill?

I can't really post the code as there is a lot of it, and it is split up into smaller methods which makes it harder to pull out individual items. E.g:

```
public SqlConnection Connection
{
    get
    {
        this._connection.Open();
        return _connection;
    }
}

public IDataReader RetrieveRecord(int Id)
{
    //SP
    SqlCommand cmd = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SelectRecord";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tID", Id));

    //instruct the data reader to close its connection when its Close method is         called by passing the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection 
    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Nothing massively complex, I just don't understand why this connection is now throwing an exception.

Comment: you are opening the connection in public SqlConnection Connection() function but never close in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.  Two reboots cleared whatever was keeping the connection open.

Comment: I would still considering refactoring the code so the connections are closed nicely.

Comment: I 100% agree. The problem, as is nearly always the case, in convincing a project manager that spending time re-writing something which technically works is worth the cost.

Comment: Know the feeling. However, after running into this issue you might have a point to convince him. Anyway, good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The DAL is not stable enough:

You open a Connection that is not closed if something goes wrong in RetrieveRecord.

You should create a new connection inside RetrieveRecord and close it there in a finally block.

Opening a connection is cheap thanks to Connection Pooling.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the line

```
this._connection.Open();
```

Because you are trying to open an already opened connection.

Try this to check before opening a connection:

```
 if (this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            this._connection.Open();
```

Comment: Yip I'm aware of that, as I said in the original post, but I'm looking for any other potential reasons for the lock considering the class has not changed and has worked fine for months.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about killing process, I think you know c# well.

You should always use

```
using()
{

}
```

Like:

```
using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
  // Do something with con
     using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("cmdText",con))
     {
        // Do something with cmd
     }
}
```

You know that SqlCommand and SqlConnection implement `IDisposable`

So when you put those objects within `using`, the connection closing and clean up job is automatically done.

No need to close the connection manually in the code, since `using` will do the work for you.